# How to Solve: $2014 ^{2015} \pmod 7$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$2014^{2015}\pmod 7$$
How do you find the mod of above without using a calculator.

Comment: Do the method of repeated squaring. Basically whats 2014^1 mod 7, 2014^2 mod 7, 2014^4 mod 7, until you can get 2015 in terms of the resulting squares.

Comment: Or you could find a pattern such as 2014^(4k) mod 7 = 1...This is just an example

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key idea here is [**Fermat’s little theorem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), which tells us that if $p$ is a prime and $a$ is an integer coprime to $p$, then
$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$$
Since $7$ is prime and $2014/7$ isn't an integer, we have
$$2014^{7-1} \equiv 2014^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$$
We can also note that
$$2015 = 335 \times 6 + 5,$$
and so we have
$$2014^{2015} \equiv (2014^6)^{335} \times 2014^5 \equiv 2014^5 \pmod 7$$
That gets us most of the way, then we observe that
$$2014 = 287 \times 7 + 5,$$
and so
$$2014^5 \equiv 5^5 \equiv 25^2 \times 5 \equiv 4^2 \times 5 \equiv 16 \times 5 \equiv 3 \pmod 7$$
We can now roll up these congruences to observe that
$$\boldsymbol{2014^{2015} \equiv 3 \pmod 7}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$2014^{2015}\equiv 5^{2015}=5^{3\times 671 +2}\equiv 125^{671}\times 5^2\equiv -1^{671}\times 4\equiv -4\equiv 3\text{(mod 7)} $$

Comment: how do you come up with $5^{2015}=5^{3\times 671 +2}$